# Perfom PHP "action=add" command then divert to another page

Tags: javascript, html

I am looking for a solution so that when a consumer clicks on a website link (A php action=add command) both the php action=add command is carried out and afterwards the consumer is diverted to another php page.

It sounds very simple, but I am struggling to get **both** actions carried out.

I have tried various bits of code unsuccessfully including using a clickable button link followed by a divert but this just does the divert .......(code below)

```
<button id="myBtn"><a href="product.php?action=add&amp; etc etc">Add to list</button>
  <script>
    var btn = document.getElementById('myBtn');
    btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
      document.location.href = 'thankyou.php';
    });
  </script>
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: What does this have to do with PHP?

Comment: Sorry I am new to this ...I thought as there is php code involved it should be tagged php

Comment: Mixing PHP and JavaScript actions requires AJAX: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started

Comment: The OP is not making a request to a PHP script @EmilS.Jørgensen. They are trying to redirect to a PHP page.

Comment: @JayBlanchard OP is trying to request the url in the `a` tag on the server and then redirect to another page.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use PHP, then this will be a lot easier:

```
<?php if(isset($_GET['action'])){
//Do something with action
header ("location: thankyou.php");
} ?>

<form action="_self" method="get" target="_self">
    <button name="action" value="add">click me</button>
</form>
```

**AJAX Solution**

Here is an example AJAX using your code:

```js
var httpRequest;

function makeRequest(url, callback) {
  httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();

  httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (httpRequest.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
      if (httpRequest.status === 200) {
        callback();
      }
    }
  };
  httpRequest.open('GET', url);
  httpRequest.send();
}


var btn = document.getElementById('myBtn');
btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  makeRequest('product.php?action=add', function() {
    //window.location.href = "thankyou.php"
    alert("HERE WE GO TO A NEW PAGE")
  });
});
```

```html
<a id="myBtn" href="#Thank you">Add to list</a>
```

Be warned! AJAX is quite advanced JavaScript

Comment: @NeilG Look at some tutorials? http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp

Comment: the php version might work but trying to put  add&amp;id=<?=$id_var?>  in the  value="add" section doesnt work because the   "&amp;id=" gets encoded into html entities .  Any ideas ?

Comment: If html entities is your problem, then simply encode and decode your string: http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php

Comment: unfortunately it's beyond my knowledge scope of how to get html special entities into the value="add" part of the PHP example above.  product.php?action=add%26id%3D<?=$id_var?>
vacancy.php?action=add&amp;id=<?=$id_var?>

Comment: I meant' -unfortunately it's beyond my knowledge scope of how to get html special entities into the value="add" part of the PHP example above.                              All I get is                                                                                     product.php?action=add%26id%3D<?=$id_var?>                                         When I want                                                                                product.php?action=add&amp;id=<?=$id_var?>                                                   I can't resolve this on my own so help greatly appreciated...

Comment: Okay, maybe we start from the basics. To understand how to send formdata: [w3schools form](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_method.asp). To insert more advanced actions: [php.net urlencode](http://php.net/urlencode) / [php.net urldecode](http://php.net/urldecode).